# Draw a line from parent ng repeat element to child ng repeat element using CSS

Tags: css, angularjs

I have to draw a line from parent to child item here is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hRXjVSAM3uxL7tTA2Wr?p=preview)

```
 <div ng-repeat="menu in menus">{{menu.menu.menuName}} <div ng-repeat="men in menu.menuTreeList" ng-style="{'margin-left':'120px'}">{{men.menu.menuName}}
```

Is it possible to draw from parent to all of its children like the diagram below??

[image]

Comment: what does "draw a line" mean, exactly?  a vertical line? a horizontal line? to *which* child element? all of them? only one of them?  it's not clear what you are trying to ask here at all.

Comment: Sorry i need to have line from parent to all of its children!

Comment: and a horizonatal line to show they are related!

Comment: that still doesn't explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Where do you want the start points and the end points of the lines to be? and how does a horizontal line show a relationship between two items that are stacked vertically?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with Angular or JS. It's pure CSS problem and not also very difficult. Style `:before` pseudo elements by adding borders and position them accordingly.